# How can a Qt/Qml app authenticate to GAE flask app?

Tags: python, qt, google-app-engine

I recently wrote a simple Google App Engine app using flask web framework. I used flask-login and flask-restful libraries to handle authentication and provide a simple RESTful api for the app. My next step is to have a Qt/Qml app login to the GAE app and have it use the REST api I created. The app is written in Qt 5.4 and runs on multiple desktop and mobile platforms. I tried using Qml WebView with Qt 5.4 to see if I could get authentication to happen successfully and then use the cookie produced during authentication to make RESTful calls from a separate network connection using QNetworkAccessManager. This never worked as I was unable to get the cookies from WebView. I am at a bit of a loss of how else I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question. Seems like it would have generated some response/interest. I'm trying to find out what kind of REST APIs people are using with Qt apps. Is it not that common?

Comment: I'm not (yet) familar with Qt. But I would look first in the networking library. There's gotta be some HTTP request stuff in there. And GAE supports OAuth2 flow(s) from the command line. So it's gotta be possible, right?